# Wildcard search of an elements id using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
if($("div[id*='*test-*-0-value']").length > 0){
    // do stuff
}
```

Unfortunatly the wild card `*test-*-0-value` isn't working. What's the best way to do a search so that i can test for any ID value that has `*test-*-0-value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), which are also [natively supported in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

- `[id*='...']` - The id must contains `...`.
- `[id$='...']` - The id must end with `...`.

Code:

```
if ($("div[id*='test-'][id$='-0-value']").length) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [a regex filter for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) that allows regex to be used for selection.

With this code, you can try this:

```
$("div:regex(id, .*test-.*-0-value)")
```

Also, check the [official documentation on selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 1):

use [james padolsey jquery's regex selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)   , and apply it to your example like :

```
if($("div:regex(id, *test-*-0-value").length > 0) {

}
```