# How to do the wild card search for values in java script

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I have worked on one search operation.There user can give the search key word and search(Search is a wild card search)..I tried normal searches.. that s working fine.. But i don no how to implement the regex for wild card search.. I have added the code which i tried.

```
function list(){
    var rr = ["test","ter","ting","ers Note","Esting","TEs","Tes"];

    var variable = "e";

    for(var i=0,tt=rr.length;i<tt;i++){
        var re = new RegExp('^' + variable + '.*$','i');

        var rer = rr[i];
        res = rer.match(re);

        if(res){
            console.log(res[0]);
        }
    }
}
list();
```

How to change the regex should work for this kind of searches..

t*,tes*,*er...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This post should get you started:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284691/wildcard-search-of-an-elements-id-using-jquery

Comment: also have a look at other options, like "fuzzy search", e.g. http://bit.ly/15Rpu5S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line:

```
variable = variable.replace(/(?=\*)/g,'.');
```

and change this line:

```
var re = new RegExp('^.*?'+variable+'.*$', 'i');
```

or

```
var re = new RegExp('^'+variable+'.*$', 'i');
```

Comment: I tried ur stuff with searching keyword of "te*" .. But it returns "ers Note" also.. I want the strings which i starts only "te"..how can i modify ur code...can u pls suggest me

Comment: @Gauti: You don't need to modify, put the first line after `variable` definition, and use the second pattern. Another thing, no need to put the pattern definition inside the for loop.

Comment: Ya its working fine..Thanks Casmier..Can i use this for "*ing" with other modification.. I used this  var re = new RegExp('.*^'+variable+'$', 'i'); its working well. but how can i use this in same expression.