# set div with similar elementId name to show --> jQuery/css

Tags: jquery, css

I have the situation to set all div with id "ABC_HK_...._XYZ" to show.
I just know for loop all element ID to check as found in [getElementById() wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/getelementbyid-wildcard)

But I do not understand much or different to choose and I want a simple way, e.g Jquery???
I have uncertain varied div with the name, for example, below..
`ABC_HK_KWUNTONG_XYZ`, `ABC_HK_TAIPO_XYZ`

I want like `$('ABC_HK_[*]_XYZ').style.display="block"`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcard search of an elements id using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284691/wildcard-search-of-an-elements-id-using-jquery)

Comment: did any answerl helped ?

Comment: yes, it is solved and have marked the answers. Thanks it is helpful in stackoverflow really

Answer (score 2):

So you want a selector that matches any element with class starting with `ABC_HK_` and ending in `_XYZ`. Use the following compound to select those:

```
$('[class ^=ABC_HK_][class $=_XYZ]')
```

Example:

```js
$('[class ^=ABC_HK_][class $=_XYZ]').addClass('bg-red')
```

```css
div {
  margin:2px;
  background:#ddd;
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.bg-red {
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ABC_HK_KWUNTONG_XYZ">ABC_HK_KWUNTONG_XYZ</div>
<div class="ABC_HK_K_XYZ">ABC_HK_K_XYZ</div>
<div class="ABC_HK_G_XYZ">ABC_HK_G_XYZ</div>
<div class="ABC_XYZ">ABC_XYZ</div>
<div class="ABC_HK_G_XYZ">ABC_HK_G_XYZ</div>
<div class="ABC_HK_KW_XYZ">ABC_HK_KW_XYZ</div>
<div class="ABC_HK_K">ABC_HK_K</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So they all start with ABC_HK_? If that's the case, you can use [id^="ABC_HK_"] to get any element whose ID starts with those characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo selectors e.g

```
 $("[name^=ABC_HK_][name$=_XYZ]").CSS("display","block")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `class` Equals `string`

   `$('div[class="string"').doSomething();`
2. The `class` Begins with `string`

   `$('div[class^="string"').doSomething();`
3. A part of the `class` is `string`

   `$('div[class*="string"').doSomething();`
4. The `class` Ends with `string`

   `$('div[class$="string"').doSomething();`

```js
$("div[class^='ABC_HK'][class$='_XYZ']").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ABC_HK_TRUE1_XYZ">SHOULD BE COLORED</div>
<div class="ABC_FAKSE_Z">SHOULDN'T BE COLORED</div>
<div class="ABC">SHOULDN'T BE COLORED</div>
<div class="HELLO__XYZ">SHOULDN'T BE COLORED</div>
<div class="ABC_HK_HELLO__XYZ">SHOULD BE COLORED</div>
```

[HERE IS A COMPLETE LIST OF JQUERY SELECTORS](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)